# any benefits using OAuth 2.0 instead of a custom Spring authentication/authorization server withoud third-party clients?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to develop a (REST API) web app using Spring, and for the authentication/authorization I am thinking about using OAuth 2.0, but I am not sure whether OAuth is a good option or not.

some information about my app:

1 - completely RESTful API.

2 - microservice Architecture.

3 - using the API for both web pages (maybe SPA) and mobile apps(android and ios).

4 - the API will be used only by our developers (web site developers and mobile app developers), and never by other third-party developers (as far as I know the main purpose of OAuth is for third-party applications).

based on the given information, is it a good idea using OAuth instead of a custom Spring authentication/authorization server with JWT? if yes, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some disadvantages and advantages from my past experience:

Disadvantages :

1. OAUTH authentication payload will contain : username, password, grant_type, **client_secret** and **client_id**. 
   The last two ones are specific for third-party login, do they make sense for your application and clients?
2. Spring OAUTH is a powerful library and will do a lot behind scenes. If you will need custom behavior, it will a little bit trickier to find the right hooks.
3. Development time took longer (both client and server) in comparison with simple username/password login.

Advantages :

1. The protocol is well documented, so you will have less overhead when documenting your application.
2. It will be easier to integrate with third parties (if ever is required).

P.S In your initial iteration you can start with simple login and add later third party integration(both can work together)

Comment: thank you, so should I use 'Resource owner credentials grant'?